# the whole body looks like an image but there's text

Tags: html, text, highlight

something is going on and I can't seem to find out what it is.  I have this page which was working fine then somebody made a modification and all the sudden I can't highlight any text.  It has that effect as if i would of just put images instead of text.  [here's the site](http://consultingfox.com/utp/index.html)
I didn't find anything overlapping, i have no z-indexes..help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**style.css**

```
::selection {
    background: transparent; 
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent; 
}
```

This makes the selections transparent. So it looks like no text is being selected.